# Extracting kinect depth_registered image

Tags: ros, kinect, depth-registered, image-view, depth-image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with ROS Groovy.
My problem is that I would like to extract the depth_registered image, in the same way I do it with the rgb image (in order to be able to do some processing outside ROS).

Basically, I am using the tutorial [Exporting image and video data](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data). But for depth, it doesn't work, because image is either float, either uint (see [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) for details on format)... but not bgr8 like image_view would like...

Any idea of another package doing the same thing ?
Or how I could have my images quickly, without doing all the computation by hand (or writing a node doing the transformation format) ?

Thanks in advance,

Bests regards,

Stéphane

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60312/extracting-kinect-depth_registered-image/) by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1304 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

so the solution is to take the extract_images file from the package image_view, and to modify it :

just modify the

```
bgr8
```

and

```
mono8
```

to

```
sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1
```

Don't forget to add at the top :

```
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
```

Last but not least add in your manifest

```
<depend package="cv_bridge"/>
```

The results will be, as in the original file, jpg files. However, don't be frightened if they look black, because values are given in meter (for depth_registered/image).

Here is the whole code :

```
// modified version for depth extraction

/*********************************************************************
* Software License Agreement (BSD License)
*
* Copyright (c) 2008, Willow Garage, Inc.
* All rights reserved.
*
* Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
* modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
* are met:
*
* * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
* notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
* * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
* copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
* disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided
* with the distribution.
* * Neither the name of the Willow Garage nor the names of its
* contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
* from this software without specific prior written permission.
*
* THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
* "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
* LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
* FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
* COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
* INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
* BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
* LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
* CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
* LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
* ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
* POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*********************************************************************/

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

class ExtractImages
{
private:
  image_transport::Subscriber sub_;

  sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr last_msg_;
  boost::mutex image_mutex_;

  std::string window_name_;
  boost::format filename_format_;
  int count_;
  double _time;
  double sec_per_frame_;

#if defined(_VIDEO)
  CvVideoWriter* video_writer;
#endif //_VIDEO

public:
  ExtractImages(const ros::NodeHandle& nh, const std::string& transport)
    : filename_format_(""), count_(0), _time(ros::Time::now().toSec())
  {
    std::string topic = nh.resolveName("image");
    ros::NodeHandle local_nh("~");

    std::string format_string;
    local_nh.param("filename_format", format_string, std::string("frame%04i.jpg"));
    filename_format_.parse(format_string);

    local_nh.param("sec_per_frame", sec_per_frame_, 0.1);

    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    sub_ = it.subscribe(topic, 1, &ExtractImages::image_cb, this, transport);

#if defined(_VIDEO)
    video_writer = 0;
#endif

    ROS_INFO("Initialized sec per frame to %f", sec_per_frame_);
  }

  ~ExtractImages()
  {
  }

  void image_cb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
  {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(image_mutex_);

    // Hang on to message pointer for sake of mouse_cb
    last_msg_ = msg;

    // May want to view raw bayer data
    // NB: This is hacky, but should be OK since we have only one image CB.
    if (msg->encoding.find("bayer") != std::string::npos)
      boost::const_pointer_cast<sensor_msgs::Image>(msg)->encoding = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1;

    cv::Mat image;
    try
    {
      image = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1)->image;
    } catch(cv_bridge::Exception)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("Unable to convert %s image to 32FC1", msg->encoding.c_str());
    }

    double delay = ros::Time::now().toSec()-_time;
    if(delay >= sec_per_frame_)
    {
      _time = ros::Time::now().toSec();

      if (!image.empty()) {
        std::string filename = (filename_format_ % count_).str();

#if !defined(_VIDEO)
        cv::imwrite(filename, image);
#else
        if(!video_writer)
        {
            video_writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("video.avi", CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),
                int(1.0/sec_per_frame_), cvSize(image->width, image->height));
        }

        cvWriteFrame(video_writer, image);
#endif // _VIDEO

        ROS_INFO("Saved image %s", filename.c_str());
        count_++;
      } else {
        ROS_WARN("Couldn't save image, no data!");
      }
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "extract_images", ros::init_options::AnonymousName);
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  if (n.resolveName("image") == "/image") {
    ROS_WARN("extract_images: image has not been remapped! Typical command-line usage:\n"
             "\t$ ./extract_images image:=<image topic> [transport]");
  }

  ExtractImages view(n, (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "raw");

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

Have a good day everyone,

Bests,

Stéphane

[EDIT] : SYNCHRONIZED VERSION for extracting rgb and depth at the same time. It may not be the best solution (using API would be better), but at least it works. I did not programm it (one of my colleague did this trick) and I do not clean the code, I let it "as it", and just hope it can help people.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>

#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

using namespace std;
// Initializing the counters
int count_rgb = 1;
int count_depth = 1;
double spf;
//
  cv::Mat image1;
void depthToCV8UC1(const cv::Mat& float_img, cv::Mat& mono8_img);
//
// Function for converting the msg to jpg
void extraction(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg, int* count, ros::NodeHandle& node_handle)
{
    //ROS_WARN("Entering extraction.");
    // May want to view raw bayer data
    // NB: This is hacky, but should be OK since we have only one image CB.
    if (msg->encoding.find("bayer") != std::string::npos)
    {
      if (strcmp(msg->encoding.c_str(),"32FC1")==0)
      {
      boost::const_pointer_cast<sensor_msgs::Image>(msg)->encoding = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1;
      }else
    {
     boost::const_pointer_cast<sensor_msgs::Image>(msg)->encoding = "mono8";
    }
    }

    cv::Mat image;
    try
    {
    if (strcmp(msg->encoding.c_str(),"32FC1")==0)
      {
    //ROS_WARN("Sharing depth image.");
      image = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1)->image;
//
     depthToCV8UC1(image, image1);
    image = image1;
//
      }else
    {
    //ROS_WARN("Sharing rgb image.");
     image = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image;
    }
      
    } catch(cv_bridge::Exception)
    {
     if (strcmp(msg->encoding.c_str(),"32FC1")==0)
      {
      ROS_ERROR("Unable to convert %s image to 32FC1", msg->encoding.c_str());
      }else
    {
     ROS_ERROR("Unable to convert %s image to bgr8", msg->encoding.c_str());
    }
      
    }

    if (!image.empty()) {
    //ROS_WARN("Image converted.");
    std::string filename;
    std::stringstream sstm;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::string path1_string;
    node_handle.getParam("path1", path1_string);
    std::string path2_string;
    node_handle.getParam("path2", path2_string);
    /*if (node_handle.hasParam("path"))
    {
    ROS_WARN("the path.c_str() is %s",path_string.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
    ROS_WARN("No path parameter found");
    }*/

    oss << *count;
    if (strcmp(msg->encoding.c_str(),"32FC1")==0)
        {
    //ROS_WARN("Creating depth name.");
    sstm << path1_string.c_str() << "depth_" << oss.str() << ".jpg";
        }else
    {
    //ROS_WARN("Creating rgb name.");
    sstm << path2_string.c_str() << "rgb_" << oss.str() << ".jpg";
    }
    filename = sstm.str();
    
    cv::imwrite(filename, image);
    ROS_INFO("Saved image %s", filename.c_str());
        *count = *count +1;
        } else {
        ROS_WARN("Couldn't save image, no data!");
        }
    
}



void callback(ros::NodeHandle& node_handle, const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& Depth_msg, const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& RGB_msg)
{   
    //ros::Rate loop_rate(30);
    //ROS_WARN("Entering the callback.");
    node_handle.getParam("sec_per_frame",spf);
    //secperframe(node_handle,spf);
    int a= 1.0/spf;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(a);
    //ROS_INFO("looprate %i",a);
    //ROS_WARN("Starting extraction of depth.");
    extraction(Depth_msg,&count_depth, node_handle);
    //ROS_WARN("Starting extraction of rgb.");
    extraction(RGB_msg,&count_rgb, node_handle);
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  
  // Initialization
  ros::init(argc, argv, "extraction_synchronized");

  // Handler
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // Handler
  ros::NodeHandle nh_priv("~");

  // Suscribers to the RGB and depth kinect message
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> depth_sub(nh, "depth_image", 10);
    ROS_INFO("%s", "Suscriber of Depth set");
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> rgb_sub(nh, "rgb_image", 10);
    ROS_INFO("%s", "Suscriber of RGB set");
  
  // Aproximate Time Synchronizer
typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image> MySyncPolicy;
  // ApproximateTime takes a queue size as its constructor argument, hence MySyncPolicy(10)
  message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), depth_sub, rgb_sub);
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback,nh_priv,_1, _2));
  ROS_INFO("%s", "Depth and RGB synchronized");

  ros::spin();


  return 0;
}

// ADDED to have good conversion
void depthToCV8UC1(const cv::Mat& float_img, cv::Mat& mono8_img){
  //Process images
  if(mono8_img.rows != float_img.rows || mono8_img.cols != float_img.cols){
    mono8_img = cv::Mat(float_img.size(), CV_8UC1);}
  cv::convertScaleAbs(float_img, mono8_img, 100, 0.0);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Faizan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/4585/faizan-a./) on 2013-07-16**:
Hi, Thanks for the answer. I tried your code but i still get black jpg images. What i would like to have is images similar to /depth_registered/image so I can extract depth information to generate point clouds. Can you tell me how to achieve that? Thanks,

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-07-16**:
Black jpeg images is normal, as the information is coded as a distance, so it won't go until value 255 :-) if you try to watch the images (for example in matlab with the function imagesc) you will see what I mean.
I edited my answer to have also a synchronized extraction of rgb and depth.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-07-16**:
What I mean is that you have to "rescale" the pixel intensity values of the images in order to have an image "as you see in ROS".

**Comment by [Faizan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/4585/faizan-a./) on 2013-07-16**:
That did the trick for me. Thanks a lot Stephane :)